# CustomAuth attribute as simply as possible

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I wanted to test very simple auth layer

```
 public class CustomAuth : AuthorizeAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{

    public CustomAuth()
    {
    }

    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        var cookies = context.HttpContext.Request.Cookies;

        var ok = cookies["Auth0"] == "asdf";
        if (!ok)
        {
            context.Result = new StatusCodeResult((int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
[CustomAuth]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

And when there's no cookie named `Auth0` with value `asdf` then everything work's fine, but when I add it then `No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found.`

I tried setting `context.Result = ...;` to e.g `new OkResult()` or `RedirectToActionResult` and it worked, but I just want to let him go straight to that `Index` instead of moving everything from that action to that `OnAuthorization` method

how can I achieve that?

Comment: A 403 response within MVC triggers the default authentication stack and attempts to trigger a `Forbid` on the default authentication scheme. If you have custom authentication, you should still try to create a custom authentication scheme for this to make proper use of it throughout the framework. That will also allow you to set up your own behavior for what should happen when a 403 is generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `CustomAuth`, it inherited from `AuthorizeAttribute`. The Authentication middleware will check the identity by default authentication scheme.

If you prefer go to `Index` without configuring any authentication, you could try change `AuthorizeAttribute` to `Attribute` like

```
public class CustomAuth : Attribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{

    public CustomAuth()
    {
    }

    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        var cookies = context.HttpContext.Request.Cookies;

        var ok = cookies["Auth0"] == "asdf";
        if (!ok)
        {
            context.Result = new StatusCodeResult((int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How does one tell this filter what scheme to use?